# Paypal automatic charge system

Tags: php, html, paypal, e-commerce, payment

I'm looking into to having users on one of my applications pay for a service. I'd like to do so with Paypal and have where the they submit a form with their information and automatically be charged the amount. I have successfully created an HTML form that submits to payment section on Paypal, but the problem I am having is auto charging the purchaser. I encounter a problem where I have to manually claim the payment. This might not be the right place to be asking this, but worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the manual, please. https://www.paypal.com/pdn-recurring

Comment: Yes I did, and I suppose I will have to pay for such a service to right?

Comment: If you read the page, and still have questions, you probably should contact paypal. We're not the paypal support line here, ya know :)

Comment: I know lol, but I feel like this could be a question to ask the Stack dev community. All I need to know is how to auto bill/charge a user for free.

Comment: I think this line says it all: "Subscriptions and Recurring Payments is only available for Business or Premier accounts."

Comment: I do have a business account though and I don't pay a dime, I'll just get a hold of them instead.

Comment: Subscriptions and Recurring Payments are free with Website Payments Standard and Express Checkout.